# Does not work when i select the same file again:Index was outside the bounds of array error any idea

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

For the first time when ever i choose the file it works fine.when I agian choose  same file with updated values it gives :Index was outside the bounds of array error any idea what went wrong  and how can i achieve this? I am using same excel file with updated data.
here is the below code:

```
  lblDisplay.Text = string.Empty;
   if (radSite.Checked==true)
            {
                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    path = openFileDialog.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog.FileName;
                }
                string constring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" + path + "; Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml";
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constring);
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    dt = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString(); //am getting error at this point
                        i++;
                    }

                    for (int j = 0; j < excelSheets.Length; j++)
                    {
                        string query = "SELECT * FROM [" + excelSheets[j] + "]; ";
                        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, constring);

                        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                        string sCode = string.Empty;
                        string sdescription = string.Empty;
                        adp.Fill(ds);

                        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                        {
                            sCode = Convert.ToString(dr[1]);
                            sdescription = Convert.ToString(dr[2]);
                            // if (!(string.IsNullOrEmpty(hCode) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(description)))
                            {

                                dboject.InsertSiteNameIntoDatabase(sCode, sdescription);

                            }
                        }


                    }
                    lblDisplay.Text = "Inserted successfully";
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    dboject.VMSLog(ex.Message);

                }
                finally
                {
                    con.Close();

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing array `excelSheets` on counter `i` , you are probably initialiazing `i`  once at the start of your program and then you are not resetting it back to `0` in your code. That is why you are getting the exception. In your code, where you are defining the array `excelSheets`, after that set `i` to `0` like:

```
String[] excelSheets = new String[dt.Rows.Count];
i = 0; //here
//then rest of your code
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    excelSheets[i] = row["TABLE_NAME"].ToString(); 
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Yes, after posting the problem understood my mistake...thanks

Comment: @kida, you are welcome, Also remember to use different counter variables for iterations, this will make your code easier to read and debug